# Apache Ignite: choose server node client node will connect to

Tags: java, ignite

Assume there are 2 server nodes and 2 client nodes A and B.

I want to protect against split brain scenario. In case server nodes splits in 2 clusters I want client B to connect to that one (if both is reachable), which A is connected to.

Is it possible?

Comment: What is the scenario where server nodes split but remain connectible by both clients A and B?

Answer (score 0):

If we are talking about thick clients (Ignite client nodes) they will reconnect automatically to the surviving server node so you don't need to worry.

If we are taking about thin clients (such as JDBC) just specify the same IP of server.